# View not moving up when keyboard appears

Tags: ios

i have a UI textfield in a subview.I am adding it to a view .When the keyboard pops-up ,i want to animate the view to which i am adding this subview.I have written all my textfield delegate functions in my subview class only.So if i use Animate textfield function it doesn't move the parent view instead thy subview is animated....please help me

Comment: Im not sure i have fully grasped what you want here.. but this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present?rq=1

Comment: Can you post the code you have used please

Comment: can you show some code..so that we could figure out whats the problem...

Comment: sorry i can't add my code @adam.Jus tis simple,am adding a subview which has a text filed in it.When the user clicks the textfield,keyboard appears . At that time i want to move the whole view up and not the view which has  the textfield.....thanks in advance

Comment: You have to manually move up the view by subscribing to system notification that fires when the keyboard appears/disappears and changing the frame property of the view by yourself

Comment: This is not automatic behavior. You have to code it, but Apple provides sample code. Of course, this has been asked many times before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present?rq=1

Comment: Here you can find the best solution ever for use of UiviewCotroller, UITableView and UiScrollView with UITextfields.
Here you go:  https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                                   object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                                   object:nil];
```

in the `viewDidLoad`

and then this

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // the keyboard is hiding reset the table's height
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration =
    [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y += 160;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.view.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // the keyboard is showing so resize the table's height
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration =
    [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y -= 160;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"ResizeForKeyboard" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:animationDuration];
    self.view.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

in your view controller

Most likely you will have to change the value (160) that I put here based on your specific view

Comment: I am trying @Vik.... ll let u no i a while....

Comment: :Its working Great...thanks a lot.....

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please upvote and accept the answer so that people looking for the same thing can be helped in the future? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

have you tried **textFieldDidBeginEditing** i don know whether you tried this or not and whether it is proper way or not.  I used this it is working less lines to achieve

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    self.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, -300, 320, 700);

}
```

this will move your root view to top so your sub view automatically will move to top text field will not be hide behind keyboard and sorry i don have reputation to comment